# Is there a way for a filter to read frame metadata values?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have some short videos taken with an old Sony digital camera that had a "spot exposure meter" setting. Videos taken with this setting on (it should be automatically ignored for video, stupid Sony engineers!) show abrupt changes of brightness when the scene center spot color changes.
I have successfully corrected them with ffmpeg, using the `eq=brightness=` filter and an expression wich is a function of the frame number.
First I have used this command to draw a graph of the average Y versus frame number:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vf signalstats,drawgraph=lavfi.signalstats.YAVG:min=0:max=255:slide=picture:size=1900x256,vflip,drawgrid=w=20:h=20:color=silver,drawgrid=w=100:h=100:color=red YAVG.bmp
```

Here is the graph for part of a video. Note how average Y varies (0 is on top) with absolutely no change in the scene shown, only slight camera movements:

[image]

Then I have made a very simple C# application to show the graph, capture my mouse clicks on selected points of the curve (which determine a polygonal line adjusted to the curve), and with their X, Y values (which correspond to frame number, average Y) build an expression for the brightness correction as a function of the frame number n. Here is the (most impressive) result for a video about 1 minute long:

```
eq=brightness='if(lt(n,66),(n-0)*-0.00764/66+0.103,if(lt(n,81),(n-66)*-0.202/15+0.0955,if(lt(n,100),(n-81)*-0.0516/19+-0.106,if(lt(n,115),(n-100)*0.124/15+-0.158,if(lt(n,133),(n-115)*0.0716/18+-0.0334,if(lt(n,141),(n-133)*0.00382/8+0.0382,if(lt(n,152),(n-141)*-0.148/11+0.042,if(lt(n,176),(n-152)*0.00303/24+-0.106,if(lt(n,187),(n-176)*0.134/11+-0.103,if(lt(n,250),(n-187)*0.13/63+0.0305,if(lt(n,286),(n-250)*-0.141/36+0.16,if(lt(n,313),(n-286)*0.0878/27+0.0191,if(lt(n,374),(n-313)*-0.0649/61+0.107,if(lt(n,382),(n-374)*-0.0693/8+0.042,if(lt(n,406),(n-382)*0.0731/24+-0.0273,if(lt(n,427),(n-406)*-0.064/21+0.0458,if(lt(n,437),(n-427)*0.0411/10+-0.0182,if(lt(n,455),(n-437)*-0.135/18+0.0229,if(lt(n,470),(n-455)*0.0546/15+-0.112,if(lt(n,511),-0.0577,if(lt(n,520),(n-511)*-0.0243/9+-0.0577,if(lt(n,552),(n-520)*0.12/32+-0.0819,if(lt(n,600),(n-552)*0.0458/48+0.0382,if(lt(n,650),(n-600)*-0.0535/50+0.084,if(lt(n,689),(n-650)*0.00764/39+0.0305,if(lt(n,706),(n-689)*-0.12/17+0.0382,if(lt(n,714),(n-706)*0.00303/8+-0.0819,if(lt(n,731),(n-714)*0.0334/17+-0.0789,if(lt(n,814),(n-731)*-0.112/83+-0.0455,if(lt(n,879),(n-814)*0.234/65+-0.158,if(lt(n,900),(n-879)*-0.0344/21+0.0764,if(lt(n,914),(n-900)*-0.00382/14+0.042,if(lt(n,932),(n-914)*0.0458/18+0.0382,if(lt(n,1010),(n-932)*-0.0153/78+0.084,if(lt(n,1026),(n-1010)*-0.16/16+0.0687,if(lt(n,1043),(n-1026)*0.0546/17+-0.091,if(lt(n,1081),(n-1043)*0.00607/38+-0.0364,if(lt(n,1140),(n-1081)*-0.115/59+-0.0303,if(lt(n,1163),-0.146,if(lt(n,1184),(n-1163)*0.112/21+-0.146,if(lt(n,1206),(n-1184)*0.0525/22+-0.0334,if(lt(n,1221),(n-1206)*-0.00764/15+0.0191,if(lt(n,1231),(n-1221)*0.0649/10+0.0115,if(lt(n,1240),0.0764,if(lt(n,1262),(n-1240)*-0.101/22+0.0764,if(lt(n,1272),(n-1262)*-0.0971/10+-0.0243,if(lt(n,1295),(n-1272)*-0.0577/23+-0.121,if(lt(n,1344),(n-1295)*0.158/49+-0.179,if(lt(n,1386),(n-1344)*0.09/42+-0.0212,if(lt(n,1403),(n-1386)*0.00382/17+0.0687,if(lt(n,1451),(n-1403)*-0.194/48+0.0725,if(lt(n,1460),-0.121,if(lt(n,1502),(n-1460)*0.282/42+-0.121,if(lt(n,1527),(n-1502)*0.0573/25+0.16,if(lt(n,1554),(n-1527)*0.00382/27+0.218,if(lt(n,1575),(n-1554)*-0.0344/21+0.221,if(lt(n,1600),(n-1575)*-0.227/25+0.187,if(lt(n,1621),(n-1600)*-0.0577/21+-0.0394,if(lt(n,1643),(n-1621)*-0.0273/22+-0.0971,if(lt(n,1660),(n-1643)*0.0152/17+-0.124,if(lt(n,1682),(n-1660)*0.147/22+-0.109,if(lt(n,1707),(n-1682)*0.0649/25+0.0382,if(lt(n,1748),(n-1707)*0.0115/41+0.103,if(lt(n,1761),(n-1748)*-0.0764/13+0.115,if(lt(n,1771),(n-1761)*-0.0716/10+0.0382,if(lt(n,1797),(n-1771)*-0.0516/26+-0.0334,if(lt(n,1846),(n-1797)*-0.0394/49+-0.085,-0.124)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))':eval=frame
```

Well, but it does work, and gives very good results!

But my question here is: Does anyone know if there is a way for the `eq` filter to directly read the YAVG metadata value, as `drawgraph` does, and avoid all that work with a polygonal function?